# KafkaProducer stops on application startup, saying "Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 30000 ms"

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

I'm trying to run a custom Spring cloud Stream app starter, and getting the following INFO log,

```
2017-11-14 14:59:24.600  INFO 30300 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version : 0.10.1.1
2017-11-14 14:59:24.600  INFO 30300 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId : f10ef2720b03b247
2017-11-14 14:59:24.747  INFO 30300 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.producer.KafkaProducer     : Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 30000 ms.
2017-11-14 14:59:24.768  INFO 30300 --- [           main] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'websocket-source.output' has 1 subscriber(s).
2017-11-14 14:59:24.773  INFO 30300 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 0
2017-11-14 14:59:24.906  INFO 30300 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
```

My problem is my app doesn't work as intended (I can't connect to the websocket server, which this app will bring up) so I expect some clues from the kafka log. May be some missing dependency but I couldn't find one.

Is it an error? How can I debug this?

Comment: Would be great to have your app somewhere on GitHub to let us pull it and play locally.

Comment: https://github.com/krishnaprasadas/websocket/tree/websocket-source/spring-cloud-starter-stream-source-websocket/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/app/websocket/source

Comment: There are a lot of note about `sink` yet. More over it isn't clear what you do to run the app. Do you follow this instruction: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/docs/Celsius.RC1/reference/html/_introduction.html#_creating_custom_artifacts ?

Comment: Yes, I followed the document. I generate the app using ./mvnw clean install -PgenerateApps and ran the generated app.

Comment: I don't know what you don't like, but that works well for. I use `-PgenerateApps`, then jump into the `/apps/websocket-source-kafka-10`. Performs its `mvnw package`. Go into the `/target` and run `java -jar websocket-source-kafka-10-1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar`. I get fully blown Spring Boot app for this Websocket Source Microservice based on the Kafka Binder. Then I go to the browser and perform `http://localhost:8080/websocket` and get an answer like `Can "Upgrade" only to "WebSocket".` All of that confirms that application works well. Not sure what you are doing wrong. Sorry, no help from me

Comment: I tried with a java websocket client and found that I'm getting an authentication error (401), "javax.websocket.DeploymentException: The HTTP response from the server [401] did not permit the HTTP upgrade to WebSocket"

Comment: Right. yo have to authenticate indeed. By default SpringSecurity is turned on. Well, you can switch it off, though - `security.basic.enabled=false`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build Spring Boot Web application, you should keep in mind that security is switched on by default - HTTP Basic Authorization

The default user is, err, `user`.

The generate password you can find in logs. For example:

```
2017-11-14 11:56:09.756  INFO 7304 --- [           main] b.a.s.AuthenticationManagerConfiguration :

Using default security password: 396c8870-f36e-44a5-aaea-735d5a8e950a
```

Although you can turn it off as well. For example command line arg:

```
--security.basic.enabled=false
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.8.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-switch-off-spring-boot-security-configuration